# nominatim errors with php

Tags: php, nominatim

I tried on my application to geolocate addresses and make them appear on a map, but I encounter a problem in the code.

This shows all the time "Unknown location" instead of the name of the city.

```
$country_name = "";  
$name = "";

$url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=".$lat."&lon=".$lng."&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";
$json_response = @file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json_response);

if (property_exists($data, 'error'))
return __("Unknown location");
else
{
  try {
    $name = $data->{'address'}->{'road'};
  } catch(Exception $e){}

  try{
    $country_name = $data->{'address'}->{'country'};
  }catch(Exception $e){}

  if($country_name && $name)
  return $name." / ".$country_name;
  elseif($country_name)
  return $country_name;
  elseif($name)
  return $name;
}
  return __("Unknown location");
}
```

**The error message is :**

> Message : Trying to get property of non-object File :
>   .../lib/helper/GlobalHelper.php Line : 422 =>     $country_name =
>   $data->{'address'}->{'country'};

Comment: After your `json_decode()`, do a `var_dump($data);` and see if it was decoded properly and what the result looks like. Add the output to the question as well so we know what the variable contains, or we won't have a chance to know. Also, this `$data->{'address'}->{'country'}` can be written as: `$data->address->country`

Comment: I do this :
$data=json_decode($json_response);
var_dump($data);

And : $country_name = $data->address->country;

But i have the same error

Comment: `var_dump($data);` will only output the contents of that variable. That's for debugging so we can see what the variable actually contains. It doesn't solve anything in itself. Please post the output of the `var_dump($data);` and we might have a chance of helping.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this code found on Google :

```
$country_name = "";
$name = "";

$url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=".$lat."&lon=".$lng."&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0");
$jsonfile = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$RG_array = json_decode($jsonfile,true);

return __($RG_array['address']['city'].' ( '.$RG_array['address']['state'].' )');
```

Now, the last problem is for some cities, the name appears, for others not ... and i have this message : "Undefined index: city". Only "State" appears